# Ubuntu on HP Zbook 15

Tags: boot, 16.04, hp

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a new HP ZBook 15 from a bootable USB.

I have problems booting up and shutting down normally, e.g. the machine just freezes after login.

As a temporary solution I boot in recovery mode:

On start up I navigate to the GRUB menu >> Ubuntu Advanced Options >> choose Ubuntu (recovery mode) >> run the fsck option >> continue booting

That works but I have to do this every time. Can someone point me to a permanent fix?

The sleep mode also does not work, so I need to restart every day currently.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem. I managed to find a work around. Open the UEFI settings (<kbd>F10</kbd> after restarting) and in Advanced choose Discrete Graphics Mode. Then run Ubuntu normally, install the Nvidia drivers, and that is. The problem is that with discrete graphics the battery dies pretty quickly. I am still looking for permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

In our HP zbook15 G5, we use the following command to setup nvidia driver and it fixed the display, hanging and all restart issues in the laptop:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-384
```

After that do a update and reboot.